# Splitting angular service file into two files

Tags: angular

I need to split my **common.service.ts** file into two parts **common.service.ts**
 and **new.service.ts**

```
export class CommonService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private env: EnvService,
    ) { }

    private service_url_1 = `${this.env.service_url}/service_1`;
    new_service_1(payload) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.service_url, payload);
    }

    //  THIS METHOD SHOULD BE IN A DIFFERENT FILE (new.service.ts)
    private service_url_2 = `${this.env.service_url}/service_2`;
    new_service_2(payload) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.service_url, payload);
    }

}
```

I want to be able to call the method **new_service_2** from a separate file (**new.service.ts**) but via common_service object itself.

```
constructor(private common_service: CommonService){}
this.common_service.new_service_2({}).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

The reason for this requirement is that I need to segregate the methods for source code management.

Note: I don't want to be making changes in common.service.ts for every new method I make in new.service.ts

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: why not use inheritance?
It's a rather odd requirement for source code management.
Why exactly do you want to segregate?

Comment: Because I have some core source code which is used to setup multiple projects, but some code needs to be project specific. My project specific code is branched out of the core source code. i will keep one file for core code and one for project specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inheritance for this.

Like, this is the first:

```
export class CommonService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private env: EnvService,
    ) { }

    private service_url_1 = `${this.env.service_url}/service_1`;
    new_service_1(payload) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.service_url, payload);
    }

}
```

and this is the second:

```
export class newService extends CommonService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private env: EnvService,
    ) { 
            super(http, env);
    }

    //  THIS METHOD SHOULD BE IN A DIFFERENT FILE (new.service.ts)
    private service_url_2 = `${this.env.service_url}/service_2`;
    new_service_2(payload) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.service_url, payload);
    }

}
```